# Raw Query with EF instantiated database keeps failing

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I Instantiated a database through entity framework as 'db',
in my c# class behind my aspx
this is how I did it:

```
var db = new fm_base_azure();
```

That works, I've already pulled out several stuff from the database.

Now I'm just trying to use a raw SQL Query to get some data from a junction table, but keep getting this error.

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'fm_app.meetingmember'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

this is the code:

```
var memberObjects = db.meetingmember.SqlQuery("SELECT e0.checkedin, e1.name
    FROM meetingmember as e0 INNER JOIN member AS e1 ON e0.member = e1.id").ToList();
```

Let me say straight away the Query Works. I've tested it in a Query string and it pulls the correct data.
So obviously it is because I'm doing it wrong, I suspect I am using a wrong reference or something weird.

Comment: Have you tried including `e0.id` in the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: You can only materialize `meetingmember` objects through this method.

Comment: Instead of selecting the columns by name, use `select e0.*`

Comment: 1:@haim770 I Haven't tried including e0.id .. but I don't see why I should, I dont need the e0.id .. I need the e1.id to match, which is represented in meetingmember as a foreign key e0.member.

Comment: @GertArnold: I don't exactly know what you mean, but am I not materializing meetingmember? that is what I want to get out of it.. a list of meetingmembers.

Do you mean I can't join?

Comment: @mshsayem: Will try this, but seems confusing? and seems ineffecient

Comment: @GertArnold

I rewrote it a bit, and now this Works ->
(but I don't do any joining, which I need to do ofc).. will keep testing (the meeting_id, is a userinput int

 `var memberObjects = db.Database.SqlQuery<meetingmember>("SELECT * FROM dbo.meetingmember WHERE meeting = "+meeting_id).ToList();`

Comment: @GertArnold

and so I made this: 
`var memberObjects = db.Database.SqlQuery<meetingmember>("SELECT dbo.meetingmember.checkedin, member.name FROM dbo.meetingmember INNER JOIN dbo.member ON dbo.meetingmember.member = dbo.member.id WHERE meeting =" + meeting_id).ToList();`

and it Works... in SQL.. the minute I threw it back though to my .cs .. it gave the same error. I dont get it

Comment: @GertArnold

So I concluded what you mean is.. I can't join something into meetingmember that isn't there, which Means I need to pull something else out than a meetingmember object, I just dont know what, but will find out

Comment: It's very simple: the query should at least supply all columns that are in `meetingmember`. For the rest you can join//filter whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

So i made it Work. Based on comments to my original post.
I selected everything from the table, and the joined table.. as you can see.

`var memberObjects = db.meetingmember.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM meetingmember as e0 INNER JOIN member AS e1 ON e0.member = e1.id WHERE e0.meeting =" + meeting_id).ToList();`

Then I realized.. since i Have entity framework my model had allready created reference because it noticed the foreign key.

meaning I ended up with just this piece of code:
`var memberObjects = db.meetingmember.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM meetingmember WHERE meeting =" + meeting_id).ToList();`

so I dont do any joining, but I don't need too, because the table already has the reference. so afterwards in a foreach loop I end up doing

`foreach(meetingmember m in memberObjects)
{
m.'ReferencedTable'.value
}`